# Asp.net Web Forms Vertical Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this code in my page in my ASP.New WebForms Project:

```
 private void populateTable(MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader)
        {
            foreach (DbDataRecord rowData in mySqlDataReader)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Text = rowData.GetInt32(rowData.GetOrdinal("truck_id")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell2);

                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                cell3.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("registration_no")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell3);

                TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                cell4.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("make")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell4);

                TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
                cell5.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("model")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell5);

                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                cell1.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("engine_no")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell1);

                TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();
                cell6.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("chassis_no")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell6);

                TableCell cell7 = new TableCell();
                cell7.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_name")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell7);

                TableCell cell8 = new TableCell();
                cell8.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_contact_no")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell8);

                TableCell cell9 = new TableCell();
                cell9.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("status")).ToString();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell9);

                tbl_TruckData.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
 }
```

How can O intergrate it to Vertical Table?

```
Truck No                  1
Registration No           AA0-1234
```

The current out is an Horizontal Table like this:

```
Truck No      Registration No     Make
   1             AA0-1234         MAN
```

Other question is it possible to embbed a `<asp:Label>` inside a `<td>` element?

For example:

```
<td> Make: </td>
<td> <asp:Label id = "TMake" runat="server"/></td>(this)
```

I've tried it but there's no out put in (this)

Answer (score 0):

> How can i intergrate it to Vertical Table.

You can start a new row each time:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
cell2.Text = rowData.GetInt32(rowData.GetOrdinal("truck_id")).ToString();
tr.Cells.Add(cell2);
tbl_TruckData.Rows.Add(tr);

tr = new TableRow();
TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
cell3.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("registration_no")).ToString();
tr.Cells.Add(cell3);
tbl_TruckData.Rows.Add(tr);
```

or look into more sophisticated binding controls like [`GridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)

> Is it possible to embbed a `<asp:Label>` inside a `<td>` element?

Sure - you may not be setting the `Text` property - either in binding or in server-side code.

```
this.TMake.Text = make;
```